# Howto get javascript value in HTML form

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got jquery using the sortable plug in.

I'm using the following function to get the values.

```
    $(function() {
            $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
                placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
            });

        });

    function overzicht(){
            var regel = '';
            $('ul#sortable li').each(function(index) {
            regel += $(this).attr('id').replace(/ /g, "") + ',';
          });
        }

<ul id="sortable">
        <xsl:for-each select="//regels/item">
        <li style="list-style:none; vertical-align:middle; min-height:50px" id="{veld[3]}" class="ui-state-default">
</li>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
```

How do I get the "regel" value in a HTML form like this?

```
<form name="cartForm" method="post" action="edit_bestellijst.asp">
  <input type="hidden" name="act" value="update" />
  <input type="hidden" name="artNr" value="***regel values***)" />
</form>
```

I'm using a bit XSL.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: You'll be needing some ids on that form and the hidden inputs.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question with more script details :)

Comment: I suggest you get a javascript book before you go any further, you are missing the basics.

Answer (score 2):

after the each loop
you should write  :

```
$("input[name='artNr']").val(regel);
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I get the values into the form?

Comment: as you know , all finput fields are submitted when post back . so after weve put the value by this jquerry code , you can get its value in the server side by Request.Form["artNr"]